# How to create a subview inside an SKScene?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, addsubview, brightness

[Before "Buy Ship" is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa9pj.png) So I am trying to create a shop where players can buy new ships. When the player hits the "buy button" image I want a combination of images and texts to become visible which acts as a sort of conformation screen. Hopefully you can see here what I mean. I would also greatly appreciate if you could tell me how to dim everything besides the conformation box. [After "Buy Ship" is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szdRR.png).

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
 import Foundation
 import SpriteKit

 class ShopPage1: SKScene{


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)

    let balance = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    balance.text = "$\(balanceAmount)"
    balance.fontSize = 100
    balance.fontColor = SKColor.green
    balance.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.87)
    balance.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(balance)

    let backToMainMenuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backButton2")
    backToMainMenuButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.25, y: self.size.height*0.89)
    backToMainMenuButton.zPosition = 1
    backToMainMenuButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    backToMainMenuButton.name = "backToMainMenuButton"
    self.addChild(backToMainMenuButton)

    let shipNameLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipNameLabel.text = "Stealth"
    shipNameLabel.fontSize = 200
    shipNameLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    shipNameLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.60)
    shipNameLabel.zPosition = 1
    shipNameLabel.name = "shipNameLabel"
    self.addChild(shipNameLabel)

    let nextShipButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "nextShipButton1")
    nextShipButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.75, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    nextShipButton.zPosition = 1
    nextShipButton.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    nextShipButton.name = "nextShipButton"
    self.addChild(nextShipButton)


    let nextShipClick = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    nextShipClick.text = "▲"
    nextShipClick.fontSize = 300
    nextShipClick.fontColor = UIColor.clear
    nextShipClick.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.753, y: self.size.height*0.36)
    nextShipClick.zPosition = 2
    nextShipClick.name = "nextShipClick"
    self.addChild(nextShipClick)


    let shipForSale = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip4")
    shipForSale.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    shipForSale.zPosition = 1
    shipForSale.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 300)
    self.addChild(shipForSale)

    let shipPodium = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shipPodium")
    shipPodium.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.527, y: self.size.height*0.31)
    shipPodium.zPosition = 1
    shipPodium.size = CGSize(width: 1200, height: 70)
    self.addChild(shipPodium)

    let shipsCostLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipsCostLabel.text = "$500"
    shipsCostLabel.fontSize = 200
    shipsCostLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    shipsCostLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.20)
    shipsCostLabel.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(shipsCostLabel)

    let shipBuyButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shipBuyButton")
    shipBuyButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.54, y: self.size.height*0.15)
    shipBuyButton.zPosition = 1
    shipBuyButton.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: 900)
    shipBuyButton.name = "shipBuyButton"
    self.addChild(shipBuyButton)

    let conformationBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "conformationBackground")
    conformationBackground.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.51, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    conformationBackground.zPosition = 2
    conformationBackground.size = CGSize(width: 1300, height: 1400)
    conformationBackground.name = "conformationBackground"
    self.addChild(conformationBackground)

    let conformationScreenTextTop = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextTop.text = "Are you sure you wish to"
    conformationScreenTextTop.fontSize = 80
    conformationScreenTextTop.fontColor = SKColor.white
    conformationScreenTextTop.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.46)
    conformationScreenTextTop.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextTop)

    let conformationScreenTextBottom = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextBottom.text = "pruchase this ship?"
    conformationScreenTextBottom.fontSize = 80
    conformationScreenTextBottom.fontColor = SKColor.white
    conformationScreenTextBottom.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.41)
    conformationScreenTextBottom.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextBottom)

    let conformationScreenTextYes = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextYes.text = "Yes"
    conformationScreenTextYes.fontSize = 150
    conformationScreenTextYes.fontColor = SKColor.green
    conformationScreenTextYes.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.30, y: self.size.height*0.30)
    conformationScreenTextYes.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextYes)

    let conformationScreenTextNo = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextNo.text = "No"
    conformationScreenTextNo.fontSize = 150
    conformationScreenTextNo.fontColor = SKColor.red
    conformationScreenTextNo.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.70, y: self.size.height*0.30)
    conformationScreenTextNo.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextNo)


}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let tappedNode = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
        let tappedNodeName = tappedNode.name


        if  tappedNodeName == "nextShipClick"{

            let sceneToMoveTo = ShopPage2(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }

        if  tappedNodeName == "backToMainMenuButton"{

            let sceneToMoveTo = MainMenuScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }




    }

}

}
```

Comment: What is the question here and what is the issue? By the way your terminilogy is wrong. You don't add subviews to the scene. You add nodes to it. In UIKit you add subviews to other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to get the conformation screen to work. Thanks to @AlessandroOrnano for all the help! I have attached my code below for future reference. If anyone has a more efficient way of doing this I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class ShopPage1: SKScene{


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)

    let balance = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    balance.text = "$\(balanceAmount)"
    balance.fontSize = 100
    balance.fontColor = SKColor.green
    balance.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.87)
    balance.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(balance)

    let backToMainMenuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backButton2")
    backToMainMenuButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.25, y: self.size.height*0.89)
    backToMainMenuButton.zPosition = 1
    backToMainMenuButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    backToMainMenuButton.name = "backToMainMenuButton"
    self.addChild(backToMainMenuButton)

    let shipNameLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipNameLabel.text = "Stealth"
    shipNameLabel.fontSize = 200
    shipNameLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    shipNameLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.60)
    shipNameLabel.zPosition = 1
    shipNameLabel.name = "shipNameLabel"
    self.addChild(shipNameLabel)

    let nextShipButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "nextShipButton1")
    nextShipButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.75, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    nextShipButton.zPosition = 1
    nextShipButton.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    nextShipButton.name = "nextShipButton"
    self.addChild(nextShipButton)


    let nextShipClick = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    nextShipClick.text = "▲"
    nextShipClick.fontSize = 300
    nextShipClick.fontColor = UIColor.clear
    nextShipClick.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.753, y: self.size.height*0.36)
    nextShipClick.zPosition = 2
    nextShipClick.name = "nextShipClick"
    self.addChild(nextShipClick)


    let shipForSale = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip4")
    shipForSale.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    shipForSale.zPosition = 1
    shipForSale.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 300)
    self.addChild(shipForSale)

    let shipPodium = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shipPodium")
    shipPodium.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.527, y: self.size.height*0.31)
    shipPodium.zPosition = 1
    shipPodium.size = CGSize(width: 1200, height: 70)
    self.addChild(shipPodium)

    let shipsCostLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipsCostLabel.text = "$500"
    shipsCostLabel.fontSize = 200
    shipsCostLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    shipsCostLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.20)
    shipsCostLabel.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(shipsCostLabel)

    let shipBuyButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shipBuyButton")
    shipBuyButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.54, y: self.size.height*0.15)
    shipBuyButton.zPosition = 1
    shipBuyButton.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: 900)
    shipBuyButton.name = "shipBuyButton"
    self.addChild(shipBuyButton)

    let shipBuyButtonClick = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipBuyButtonClick.text = "▅▅"
    shipBuyButtonClick.fontSize = 300
    shipBuyButtonClick.fontColor = UIColor.clear
    shipBuyButtonClick.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.05)
    shipBuyButtonClick.zPosition = 2
    shipBuyButtonClick.name = "shipBuyButtonClick"
    self.addChild(shipBuyButtonClick)

}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let tappedNode = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
        let tappedNodeName = tappedNode.name


        if  tappedNodeName == "nextShipClick"{

            let sceneToMoveTo = ShopPage2(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }

        if  tappedNodeName == "backToMainMenuButton"{

            let sceneToMoveTo = MainMenuScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }

        if  tappedNodeName == "shipBuyButtonClick"{

            let sceneToMoveTo = ShopPage1ConformationScreen(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
           }

    }

}

}
```

This is the code for ShopPage1ConformationScreen:

```
 import Foundation
 import SpriteKit


 let shipForSale = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip4")

 class ShopPage1ConformationScreen: SKScene{


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)

    let balance = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    balance.text = "$\(balanceAmount)"
    balance.fontSize = 100
    balance.fontColor = SKColor.green
    balance.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.87)
    balance.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(balance)

    let backToMainMenuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backButton2")
    backToMainMenuButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.25, y: self.size.height*0.89)
    backToMainMenuButton.zPosition = 1
    backToMainMenuButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    backToMainMenuButton.name = "backToMainMenuButton"
    self.addChild(backToMainMenuButton)

    let shipNameLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipNameLabel.text = "Stealth"
    shipNameLabel.fontSize = 200
    shipNameLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    shipNameLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.60)
    shipNameLabel.zPosition = 1
    shipNameLabel.name = "shipNameLabel"
    self.addChild(shipNameLabel)

    let nextShipButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "nextShipButton1")
    nextShipButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.75, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    nextShipButton.zPosition = 1
    nextShipButton.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    nextShipButton.name = "nextShipButton"
    self.addChild(nextShipButton)


    let nextShipClick = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    nextShipClick.text = "▲"
    nextShipClick.fontSize = 300
    nextShipClick.fontColor = UIColor.clear
    nextShipClick.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.753, y: self.size.height*0.36)
    nextShipClick.zPosition = 2
    nextShipClick.name = "nextShipClick"
    self.addChild(nextShipClick)



    shipForSale.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    shipForSale.zPosition = 1
    shipForSale.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 300)
    self.addChild(shipForSale)

    let shipPodium = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shipPodium")
    shipPodium.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.527, y: self.size.height*0.31)
    shipPodium.zPosition = 1
    shipPodium.size = CGSize(width: 1200, height: 70)
    self.addChild(shipPodium)

    let shipsCostLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    shipsCostLabel.text = "$500"
    shipsCostLabel.fontSize = 200
    shipsCostLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    shipsCostLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.20)
    shipsCostLabel.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(shipsCostLabel)

    let shipBuyButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shipBuyButton")
    shipBuyButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.54, y: self.size.height*0.15)
    shipBuyButton.zPosition = 1
    shipBuyButton.size = CGSize(width: 1500, height: 900)
    shipBuyButton.name = "shipBuyButton"
    self.addChild(shipBuyButton)

    let conformationBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "conformationBackground")
    conformationBackground.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.51, y: self.size.height*0.40)
    conformationBackground.zPosition = 2
    conformationBackground.size = CGSize(width: 1300, height: 1400)
    conformationBackground.name = "conformationBackground"
    self.addChild(conformationBackground)

    let conformationScreenTextTop = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextTop.text = "Are you sure you wish to"
    conformationScreenTextTop.fontSize = 80
    conformationScreenTextTop.fontColor = SKColor.white
    conformationScreenTextTop.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.46)
    conformationScreenTextTop.zPosition = 3
    conformationScreenTextTop.name = "comformationScreenTextTop"
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextTop)

    let conformationScreenTextBottom = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextBottom.text = "purchase this ship?"
    conformationScreenTextBottom.fontSize = 80
    conformationScreenTextBottom.fontColor = SKColor.white
    conformationScreenTextBottom.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.41)
    conformationScreenTextBottom.zPosition = 3
    conformationScreenTextBottom.name = "conformationScreenTextBottom"
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextBottom)

    let conformationScreenTextYes = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextYes.text = "Yes"
    conformationScreenTextYes.fontSize = 150
    conformationScreenTextYes.fontColor = SKColor.green
    conformationScreenTextYes.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.30, y: self.size.height*0.30)
    conformationScreenTextYes.zPosition = 3
    conformationScreenTextYes.name = "conformationScreenTextYes"
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextYes)

    let conformationScreenTextNo = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    conformationScreenTextNo.text = "No"
    conformationScreenTextNo.fontSize = 150
    conformationScreenTextNo.fontColor = SKColor.red
    conformationScreenTextNo.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.70, y: self.size.height*0.30)
    conformationScreenTextNo.zPosition = 3
    conformationScreenTextNo.name = "conformationScreenTextNo"
    self.addChild(conformationScreenTextNo)
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let tappedNode = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
        let tappedNodeName = tappedNode.name

        if(balanceAmount >= 500){
        if  tappedNodeName == "conformationScreenTextYes"{
            player = shipForSale
            balanceAmount -= 500
            let sceneToMoveTo = ShopPage1(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }
        }

        if  tappedNodeName == "conformationScreenTextNo"{
            let sceneToMoveTo = ShopPage1(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }



    }
}
}
```

For additional shop pages just copy and paste these sets of codes. With the exception of changing the the tapped nodes around to the correct order in which you wish to move from page to page.

Answer (score 1):

As Whirlwind said in his comment you can create an `SKNode` to the center of your scene (position `CGPoint.zero`) prepare it with all your stuff and hide it with the `alpha` properties set to 0 and put it's `zPosition` to -1 (under all the other visible nodes of your scene).

So when you button will be pressed, you simply change the `zPosition` to an highest value and the `alpha` to 1. To make more realistic these action s you could use some animations like:

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(_ duration:TimeInterval=1.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0 // Instead of a specific instance of, say, birdTypeLabel, we simply set [thisInstance] (ie, self)'s alpha
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    func fadeOut(_ duration:TimeInterval=1.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add these four sprite and label nodes to the node how would I go about doing that? conformationBackground, conformationScreenTextTop, conformationScreenTextBottom, conformationScreenTextNo

Comment: Better question when you say prepare it with all your stuff how exactly do I do that.

Comment: @Jfost99 I think this: if you have write "from your hand" all this code, I think you not have any problem to do let myNode = SKNode() ; addChild(myNode) ; myNode.position = CGPoint.zero ; myNode.zPosition =  1000 // add the elements you want to myNode. Then you don't add nothing more than the stuff explained in this answer

Comment: ok so I created a node like you said above.                                                       **let myNode = SKNode()
myNode.position = CGPoint.zero
myNode.zPosition = 0
self.addChild(myNode)**

Comment: Omano I also added my label and text nodes to this node. **let conformationBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "conformationBackground")
        conformationBackground.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.51, y: self.size.height*0.40)
        conformationBackground.zPosition = 2
        conformationBackground.size = CGSize(width: 1300, height: 1400)
        conformationBackground.name = "conformationBackground"
        _myNode.addChild(conformationBackground)_**

Comment: @AlesandroOmano My question is how do I now make the node appear and disappear, also did I add my label and text node to myNode properly?

Comment: You should play with `alpha` and `zPosition` of your node. Take present also the `paused` property for the node states

Comment: @AlesandroOrnano Can you write out the syntax for me on how to add the conformationBackground, conformationScreenTextTop, and conformationScreenTextBottom to myNode